# PowerBI DAX formula

Tags: powerbi, dax, daxstudio

In this image that is uploaded - I need to populate that total number 155k to all of the F&B positions. All of this data is being pulled from multiple different tables. I have a a total revenue calculation already populated that works under each outlet name, but wont populate under each position under those outlet names. Any advice on this?

I've tried a multitude of formulas but nothing is working.

Comment: No image included, also update your question with formulas that you have tried.